# How to get nixos configuration.nix to configure nginx?

Tags: nginx, nixos

In my configuration.nix, it says

```
services.nginx.enable=true;
services.nginx.httpConfig="a";
```

(I tried a normal file and empty string and neither worked)

upon running `nixos-rebuild switch`, it says that the server was started, but `curl localhost` connection refuses.

When I run `nginx` from the command line, it responds `could not open error log file: open() "/nix/store/HASHHERE-nginx-1.8.1/logs/error.log failed", read only filesystem`.

I looked at the conf file there `/nix/store/HASHHERE-nginx-1.8.1/conf/nginx.conf` and it's the same as the default! (`'diff nginx.conf nginx.conf.default'` returns a blank line).

Why doesn't `services.nginx.httpConfig` change the config file?

Comment: you can easily check when systemd nginx unit is doing by typing (systemctl status -l nginx)

also you might find implementation of nginx service easy to understand -> https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/web-servers/nginx/default.nix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does change the config file, but the config file doesn't get written into the nginx package. Instead it gets written to a new file in a new location.

It confused me a bit at first as well. I found it helpful to make sense of it by remembering that the nix store reflects the purity of the nix functional language - when you change something the original copy should remain the same, instead a new copy is created combined with whatever changes (it's this property that supports instant rollbacks).
The same goes for your nginx config - the package is never touched, instead a new config file is created.

As Rok says you can quickly check where the location of the config file is with `systemd status`. 
You can also read through the config section for the nginx module to see how the whole thing is implemented. In that case you will see that your `nginx.httpConfig` text gets written to a configFile in `/nix/store/HASHHERE-nginx.conf`. 
That file then gets passed directly to your nginx binary via its -c option. So the nginx systemd unit execStart command is like `${pkgs.nginx}/bin/nginx -c ${configFile}..`

PS that is also why your curl returns a connection refused - cos your nginx configuration is just 'a'! The default server is sitting in the nginx package but completely unreferenced (exactly the same thing happened to me).

Comment: PS make sure nginx.stateDir is somewhere nginx can write its logs to (the default is fine), not /nix/store/.. which only nix should write to (else you're tampering with its purity).

Comment: You can follow [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nick-b-h/7f63d6199f56abdf0c0954ca546f396d) to get an idea of what's going on.